# Doubles in MySQL

Tags: mysql, number-formatting

I created a table, which are contains some double, but when I added this number

> 7.341270020834490e+005

and the database is the following number:

> 734127.002083

cutting out some useful information. I want the hole number not just part of that

like:

> 734127.0020834490

Comment: what is the datatype of that field ? "double ?

Comment: Just curious ... what do you do with the values that requires more than 12 significant figures?

Comment: @pavium This is a measurement, where I need the hole number

Comment: sort of like measuring the Earth's circumference to the nearest 40 micrometres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax:
>   FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means
>   than values can be stored with up to M
>   digits in total, of which D digits may
>   be after the decimal point.

See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can store this as a string in your database....
and when you want to use the value just use some method in the language that you are using to convert string to double.

Comment: What impact does that have on performance opposed to using DOUBLE PRECISION and such?

Comment: i think, converting to a string is not purposeful